# How to add Welcome username in all pages

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

How to display “Welcome %username%” in all the webpages, is there any possibly to make it in the Master page? if so, where in master page should i write the code, in page_load??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [login name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginname.aspx) control in asp.net to show this information. Just place it on your Master page like this:

```
<asp:LoginView runat="server">
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        Welcome <asp:LoginName runat="server" />
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

It will show login name only for logged in users.

If you need this information somewhere else, you can use current user identity to get the name using current [http context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx):

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated)
{
     string currentUserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What you can do is define a new literal in the masterpage and upon login save the username insode this literal and add before it Welcome

Comment: the most awful way of doing it

Comment: @Ali Issa There is no way to "save" username inside literal. And why to use literal if there is an label control and LoginView control?